# What is the OPTION in the GCC's option "-Wl,OPTION"?

Tags: gcc, linker

When I read the GCC's info manual, I found the link option -Wl,OPTION:

```
`-Wl,OPTION'
 Pass OPTION as an option to the linker.  If OPTION contains
 commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.
```

But I could not find the definition of the OPTION. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The linker is called `ld`. Googling for `ld options` gives e.g. http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html

Comment: ho, I found: "if the linker is being invoked indirectly, via a compiler driver (e.g. gcc) then all the linker command line options should be prefixed by -Wl". Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It is linker options written like this (from my makefile):

```
FLAGS += -Wl,--enable-auto-import,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
```

The linker options are listed in detail on [the linker man page: ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) (the GNU linker)

Answer (score 3):

The options are for the ld linker, and are listed [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html).

Answer (score 2):

On my linker (for sh4), you type `sh4ld --help`.