# Other Linker Flags list

Tags: xcode, linker, flags

Is there a list of all flags that can be put into the `Other Linker Flags` field of the Xcode Build Settings?

I've searched the developer documentation without results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well a definitive list of all the flags supported by `ld` is available in the [`ld manpage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html), and I guess you'd have to ignore the flags that are properly supported by Xcode in order to get your list.

You can, of course, access the manpage from your Mac by firing up Terminal and typing:

```
$ man ld
```

It's also probably available from with the Xcode Documentation window.

Comment: Also, if you want to pass any of these via OTHER_LDFLAGS or "Other Linker Flags", you have to prefix with -Wl, so for example, if you want to specify -t, you have to do "-Wl,-t"

Comment: @ajh158 Oh my, thanks for pointing that! I couldn't figure out why options listed in man doesn't want to work! Can you point to some place in documentation where this is explained?

Comment: @solgar Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258998/what-is-the-option-in-the-gccs-option-wl-option) help?

Comment: The link in your answer is dead :-(

Comment: ```-filelist file[,dirname]
                 Specifies that the linker should link the files listed in file.  This is an alternative to listing the files on the command
                 line.  The file names are listed one per line separated only by newlines. (Spaces and tabs are assumed to be part of the file
                 name.)  If the optional directory name, dirname is specified, it is prepended to each name in the list file.```